# Makefiles - How do I use an eval'd variables with ifndef/ifdef?

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to figure out how to get an eval'd variable (using output from the shell) to pass conditional checks like ifndef or ifdef. I need to use the shell because I'm actually using a script that returns some output.

```
foo::
        $(eval var := $(shell echo 'hello'))
ifndef var
        @printf 'ifndef is true. var is ${var}'
else
        @printf 'ifndef is false. var is ${var}'
endif
```

Running "make foo" will output the following:

```
'ifndef is true. var is hello'
```

As you can see, ifndef doesn't find anything in var, even though printf is showing that var contains the string "hello".

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this because `ifdef` et. al. are parsed *when the makefile is read in* (note that they do not begin with a TAB character so they are not part of the recipe), and the recipe (which includes `$(eval ...)`) is not parsed until much later when make wants to build the target `foo`.

And, you cannot put `ifdef` et. al. into the recipe because if you prefix them with TAB then they get passed to the shell, not parsed by make.  In general if you want a conditional inside a recipe you have to use shell conditionals, NOT make conditionals, because the recipe is a shell script.

You can use the `$(if ...)` function:

```
foo::
        $(eval var := $(shell echo 'hello'))
        @printf 'ifndef is $(if $(var),true,false). var is ${var}'
```

But to me this looks like a mistake and you might reconsider what you're trying to do at a more fundamental level.